# How to update binary column using MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to update a MySQL table using MySQL workbench. The column i'm trying to update is varbinary type so i'm trying to cast the value from a string first.

Getting the error below:

Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks

Executing:

```
UPDATE `asterisk`.`extensions` SET `appdata`= CONVERT('peers,peer11,1', BINARY) WHERE `context`=0x6130362D6F7574676F696E67 and`exten`=0x5F2E and`priority`='13';
```

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 0: 0: MySQL_Prepared_Statement::setBlob: invalid 'parameterIndex'

SQL Statement:

```
UPDATE `asterisk`.`extensions` 
SET `appdata`= CONVERT('peers,peer11,1', BINARY) 
WHERE `context`=0x6130362D6F7574676F696E67 
  and`exten`=0x5F2E and`priority`='13'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BINARY` function can do the work

```
UPDATE `asterisk`.`extensions` 
SET `appdata`= BINARY('peers,peer11,1') 
WHERE `context`=0x6130362D6F7574676F696E67 
  and`exten`=0x5F2E 
  and`priority`='13';
```